# Missing results from elastic search when using curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying out elastic search for the first time. I just have 1 node and 1 index.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/testing/dummy/1 -d '{
                "snapshotTime" : "2012-10-31T13:31:21",
                "ratio" : "50",
                "description" : "sample description"


}'
```

I have indexed 500 such dummies to index 'testing'.

```
http://localhost:9200/testing/dummy/1
```

.
.
.
.

```
http://localhost:9200/testing/dummy/500
```

Now, when I tried a matchAll query with this data set,

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9202/_all/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{ 
    "query" : { 
        "matchAll" : {} 
    } 
}'
```

I get back only 10 results and they are random every time. However, the total hits remain 500. The hits array only contain 10 entries. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from elastic search users mailing list. (Credits: Radu Gheorghe)
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size.html

The from/size in the search API allows to control the result set size.

Answer (score 0):

`http://127.0.0.1:9200/foo/_search/?size=1000&pretty=1`

Note the size param, which increases the hits displayed from the default (10) to 1000.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html